# Is it safe to embed Facebook "App Access Token" or "App Secret" into mobile app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need access to a app access token so that I can inspect a token in my UWP app. Is it safe to embed the App Access Token into my app? Or maybe the app secret? No one appears to have a clear answer to this simple question, nor can they point me to any clear documentation that says yes or no.

A App Access Token is REQUIRED in order to inspect a user token after authenticating the user. The ONLY way you can inspect the user token is to use a App Access Token. If I am not allowed to embed a App Access Token into my app, then there is no way to inspect a user token from within a mobile client app. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should not share the app access token with anyone. So if you share the app with anyone you should not include your app access token in it

Comment: What do you hope to gain from inspecting/debugging the access token in a client-side app in the first place? Make an API request with it to get the user details, then you will know if the token is a genuine one or not. App token or app secret should not be put into client-side code, if at all avoidable. Whether the code is “compiled” somehow or not doesn’t change much in that regard IMHO.